# Source files not found on Visual Studio Code PHP Debug (WSL server)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm hosting a local copy of my website on windows 10, whereas the server is running on WSL Linux bash. I've installed Visual Studio Code, and PHP debug, configured Xdebug, and the debugging is successfully triggered from a chrome page. However, VS code then tells me that it is "unable to open" my php files. I've tried all kinds of pathMappings in the json configuration file, but nothing seems to work.

Could someone help me there ? Thanks a lot in advance !

My settings :

Local website location : D:/local_websites/
Corresponding path from linux server : /mnt/d/local_websites/

xdebug.ini :

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

launch.json:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000,
        "pathMappings": {
            "/mnt/d/": "d:/",
        }
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error opening workspace in remote:

- Install "Remote - WSL" extension in vscode.
- In WSL go to your workspace path and enter: "code ." (or "code /mnt/d/local_websites/") and will appear a vscode remote instance.
- In this remote vscode instance go to extensions and use "Install on WSL" on your needed extensions (PHP Debug, PHP Intelephense, ...).